# Can I say : "He was made broke"?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

> He doesn't have any money. He was **made broke** in 1999.

Is it grammatically correct to use this structure?

Comment: It's *grammatically* correct; it's idiomatically *understandable.* It's not something a native speaker would say -- we'd probably use *bankrupted*.

Comment: ...or "became broke".

Comment: It would probably most commonly be said, "He was broke by 1999."

Comment: `he went broke in 1999`

Comment: BTW I can't imagine someone saying `He bankrupted.` Again more common is `The company went bankrupt` at least from my experience.

Comment: @Brandin No, not *he bankrupted* (unless that is followed by a grammatical object). But *He was bankrupted,* following the structure of the OP's example, is fine.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ok I understand now.  I still prefer "He went bankrupt" but maybe this is an Americanism.

Comment: He went *bust* in 1999.

Answer (score 2):

***Broke*** is not a technical nor legal term. It is idiomatic, but rarely in the form of *he was made broke*. It would be more usual to say *He went broke*, or 'As a result of the project's failure, *he was left broke*'. But in any formal sense the word (in the UK) would be ***bankrupt***.

One can either use *bankrupt* as an adjective, as in *he went bankrupt*, or as a transitive verb. However, because the verb is transitive one cannot say *He bankrupted*. That is not idiomatic. One could, though say *The Company, to whom he owed millions, bankrupted him*, or *his profligacy eventually bankrupted him*. But it is more usual to say, in both these cases, *made him bankrupt*.

*He bankrupted himself* is a possibility, but more usually this would be *he made himself bankrupt*.

There are two meanings associated with the verb *to bankrupt*. One is the official legal procedure involving the appointment of a *receiver*. The other is the more idiomatic sense which describes the longer process of getting into financial trouble. So *He bankrupted himself* could either mean that he voluntarily called in the Receiver and declared himself insolvent. Or it could mean something like 'As a result of financial mismanagement and loose living *he gradually bankrupted himself*'.

***Bankrupt*** also exists as a noun as in *A bankrupt cannot act as a guarantor*.

Comment: -1 The Q is not seeking alternatives to *broke,* it's not about the right word but the right collocation/ phrase.

Comment: @Kris We don't always get given what we seek. 'Broke' is a wholly inappropriate word in any formal expression of legal insolvency, which *made broke* suggests is what is being sought.

Comment: Even as it is with the answer, so with the comment: where is "technical/ legal/ formal/ insolvency" coming in from now? The question is one of grammar -- plain general English -- as clear from the simple, straightforward question. The context is neither technical nor legal, not even necessarily too formal.

Comment: But the fact that his being *broke* is given with a date (of 1999), suggests that formal bankruptcy lies at the heart of it. It is not a case of using 'broke' in the very loose sense that everyone does, such as in *I can't afford a holiday, I'm broke*. Perhaps I am over-sensitive to this, having been in the accountancy profession, but I would tend to avoid the confusion of *broke* when discussing formal bankruptcy.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine the way you have it. This sounds unusual because it wouldn't be used often. Consider this to be what's known as a *turn of phrase*, meaning

> *an expression which is worded in a distinctive way, especially one which is particularly memorable or artful.* ([Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_of_phrase))

Of course, many people enjoy the art of using a turn of phrase, and many people enjoy a good turn of phrase when they hear or see one.

In this particular case, the author appears to focus attention of the point that going broke was the deliberate consequence of some outside influence - someone or some event caused it - rather than focusing on the outcome of being broke.

It's possible (but not certain) that the author had more in mind than the plain meaning of the sentence. *Made* is used in several expressions relating to someone's achievements and success:

> a made man / has it made: assured of success or already successful.
>
> self-made man: rich and/or successful as a consequence of one's own efforts.
>
> made of money: rich.

Hence (maybe), *made broke*.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes. Because it is grammatical and does make sense.

However, the usual idiom is either "He was **left broke**" or, to a lesser extent, "He was **rendered broke**."

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very strange. Since "broke" is an informal term and "was made" sounds much more formal, the sentence is dissonant.

You can either make it all formal, or all informal, but the mix of the two makes the sentence sound "wrong," even though it is grammatically acceptable.

Informal: "He went broke in 1999."

Formal: "He was made bankrupt in 1999." or "He was rendered bankrupt in 1999."